# TF Model Sub-Classing Errors with Symbolic Tensors/Graph Execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to recreate results from a paper and I'm having a lot of issues in running a Tensorflow sub-classed model without resorting to eager execution. Even when using eager execution it seems that it isn't training properly (showing zero trainable parameters and loss metric is near constant). Any time an error is thrown the input arguments received all have 'None' shape (as shown in the error below), leading me to believe this is somehow an issue with the symbolic tensors used on execution?

This model uses the Spektral package with a dataset of labelled graphs as input. Here 'x' is the Spektral graph features, 'a' is the adjacency matrix, 'e' is the (unused) edge features matrix. 'C' is just a constant. The 'x' node features contain one-hot encodings and node coordinates which are split and treated separately throughout the model.

This is the current state of the model.

```
class egcl(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, C = InputParser()(inputs)        
        h_feat, x_feat = NodeFeatureSplitter()(x)
        distance = NodeDistance()(x_feat)
        
        # Message matrices
        m_ij_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([tf.squeeze(h_feat), distance, tf.squeeze(a)])
        m_ij = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(m_ij_input)
        m_ij = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='swish')(m_ij)
        m_ij = tf.reshape(m_ij, shape=(3, 3, 3))
        m_i = tf.reduce_sum(m_ij, axis=2) 
        
        # Update node feature
        h_i_next_input = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([distance, m_i])
        h_i_next = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(h_i_next_input)
        h_i_next = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='swish')(h_i_next)

        # Update coord feature
        x_i_next = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(m_i)
        x_i_next = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='swish')(x_i_next)
        x_i_next = x_feat + (C * distance * x_i_next)
        x_i_next = tf.squeeze(x_i_next) 

        # Fit with graph labels
        out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([h_i_next, x_i_next])
        out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(out)
        out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='swish')(out)
        out = tf.math.reduce_mean(out, axis=0)
        
        return out


# Model call
epochs = 5
model = egcl()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-03), loss=MeanSquaredError(), run_eagerly=False)
history = model.fit(loader.load(), steps_per_epoch=loader.steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs)
```

And the custom classes called are defined as follows.

```
class InputParser(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InputParser, self).__init__()
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, e = inputs
        C = tf.cast(1/(len(x)), tf.float32)
        
        return x, a, C
    

class NodeFeatureSplitter(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NodeFeatureSplitter, self).__init__()
        
    def call(self, x):
        h_feat = x[...,:2]
        x_feat = x[...,-3:]
        
        return h_feat, x_feat
    

class NodeDistance(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NodeDistance, self).__init__()
        
    def call(self, x_feat):
        norm = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
        for i in range(len(x_feat[0])):
            for j in range(len(x_feat[0][i])):
                norm = norm.write(norm.size(), tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm([x_feat[0][i] - x_feat[0][j]]))
        
        norm = norm.stack()
        norm = tf.reshape(norm, shape=(len(x_feat[0]), len(x_feat[0])))

        return norm
```

The current issue is the first concatenate layer throwing the following error,

```
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
    
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)')
```

Am I incorrectly sub-classing Model? Is this setup configured to train correctly even in eager execution mode? Please don't hesitate to ask for any clarifications or further info.

Thanks for any and all input <3

Edit: I tried Loris' suggestion of adding my layers into the **init** and calling them with 'self.'... This has gotten past the previous error however there is now another issue,

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 9
         [[node mean_squared_error/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze

W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
```

How is the loss function and squeeze causing this?

Comment: I have not test it but I think you need to define dense layers in the __init__ (or build) methode

Comment: Thanks for the input @LorisPilotto, please see my edit above.

Comment: Can you do `print(out)` before the call return to see 'out''s shape?

Comment: Output shape is (9,). I should have stated that this is the expected output shape as all graphs have 9 labels.

Comment: Once again, I have not tested it but the model's output shape need to be of the form `(nbr of samples, output dim)` (And same for the shape of the labels) so that the loss can be computed for each sample.